# Can't install Ubuntu on Surface Pro 4 after latest Windows updates

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, surface

i'd been running ubuntu 19.10 (and 19.04) on my Surface Pro 4 since January. 
Recently I started having wifi problems (not finding my wlan adapter at all) so i thought i'd reinstall fresh 19.10. Now I'm unable to install at all! Install fails with this error:

```
The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /
target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will 
not boot.
```

Then it gave a window saying it wanted to submit a bug report, but it became unresponsive at that point. (Mouse pointer & menus still active, but no button presses registered, nor did shutdown work.)

A few days ago (after the wifi problems started, before attempting the Ubuntu reinstall) I installed all available updates in Windows 10. I don't know if perhaps this locked the boot partition or something?

I also tried installing Pop_Os 19.10, which similarly failed (with "exit code 5").

Any advice?